# CMake, why OpenMP is not found by Clang?

Tags: gcc, cmake, clang, openmp

For a project that uses the OpenMP API, I'm using Clang 12.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. Also, the version of CMake is 3.16.3.

I have the following snippet. This is my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
include(FindOpenMP)
if(OPENMP_FOUND)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()
if(NOT OPENMP_FOUND)
    message(FATAL ERROR "Unable to find OpenMP library.")
endif()
```

And, the output is:

```
[cmake] -- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES) 
[cmake] -- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES) 
[cmake] -- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND) 
[cmake] FATAL ERROR Unable to find OpenMP library.
```

Instead, if I use GCC (version 9.4.0), the output is:

```
[cmake] -- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
[cmake] -- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
[cmake] -- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")
```

I know that when using Clang with OpenMP you need to use `-fopenmp=libomp`. But, how can I set up CMake so that everything works? What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not related with your problem, but proper way for include a CMake module with name started with "Find" is `find_package`: `find_package(OpenMP)`. You could also add `REQUIRED` option to that command, so CMake will stop configuring if the package is absent: `find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)`.

Comment: How do you specify `clang` as a compiler for your CMake project? There are .. wrong ways for doing that, so before going deeper it is better to be sure you use correct ways.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I specified Clang as the compiler like this: `if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang") if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 11.0) message(FATAL_ERROR "Clang version must be at least 11.0!") endif()`

Comment: What you show is just a **check** for the compiler. But how do you specify (**set**) it? By default, CMake configures the project with `gcc`.